# Why am I unable to set cookie name with PHP's setcookie()?

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I am trying to use the following code to set a cookie:

```
<?php
    setcookie("sid",      // Name
        session_id(),         // Value
        0,                    // Expiry
        "/",                  // Path
        ".mysite.com",        // Domain
        true,                 // HTTPS Only
        true);                // HTTP Only
    session_start();
    ...
```

According to my code the name should be "sid", but instead the cookie name is always "PHPSESSID". However, if I add `session_name("sid");` just before `session_start()`, then the session name IS set to "sid". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because `session_start` sets a cookie itself?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`session_start` creates a session cookie, using the `session.name` configuration value.

`session_name` can be used to override the default. You should use it (or configure it globally in `php.ini`), not manually attempt to set a cookie, as `session_start` has no idea that your custom `sid` cookie means anything relevant to sessions - for all PHP knows, that cookie might be storing whether or not the user's name is Sid.